# the past simple with SINCE

Tags: tense

**1 Jack has lost his rucksack since he left Berlin.**

Can it be recast into

**2 Jack lost his rucksack since he left Berlin.**

Answer (score 1):

Explanation:

- "has lost" is used when: the *thing* that is lost is yet to be found.

  The reason for this is "has" is in present tense, thus making sure that the *thing* is still lost.
- "lost" is used when: the *thing* that is lost maybe has already been found.

  The reason is because here, "lost" gets treated as a past tense, similar to "had lost"; therefore, it might mean that in the past he had lost the *thing*, but then found it.

Comment: Upvoted. Just to make sure that your first language is English. Is it?

Comment: @user1425 Yes. Thanks.

Comment: So: _He has lost it since he left_ OR _He lost it after he left_.

Comment: It sounds like you want to refute the correctness of "Jack lost his rucksack since he left Berlin."